# killing series of processes

Tags: bash, awk, kill

When I enter the command ps -ef |grep sharatds , I get a list of processes.

```
sharatds 13164 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [bt.C.256] <defunct>
sharatds 13165 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13199 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13233 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13267 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13301 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13335 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13369 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13403 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13437 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13471 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13505 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13539 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13573 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13607 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13641 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13675 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13709 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13743 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13777 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13811 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13845 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13879 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
sharatds 13913 13163  0 20:53 pts/2    00:00:00 [rsh] <defunct>
```

I want to kill all the processes which have the last column as defunct .

Can anybody help me with a script ?

Comment: It's better to avoid grepping `ps` if you can. Use `pgrep -u` or `pkill -u` if they're available or `ps -u` if they're not. Using `grep` runs the risk of false positives. Brandon is correct. They're already dead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do:

```
ps -ef | grep sharatds | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

Answer (score 4):

I usually do something like this:

```
kill $(ps -ef |grep sharatds|awk '{print $2}')
```

**Edit:** Wait! Those are defunct processes. They are already dead, and cannot be killed further! The parent process will have to run `wait()` to read their statuses so that they can be cleaned up and removed from the process table.

Comment: I really like this method, it's nice to note that you can also do `sudo kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep sharatds | awk '{print $2}')` if you want to "super kill" it in cases where regular kill doesn't work. (not for the faint of heart though) LOL

Comment: Or kill the parent process.  when the parent dies, the children are inherited by init (process 1) which automatically reaps the zombie children.